# What is the simplest implementation of a filter function in KDB Q?

Tags: kdb

Many functional languages have built in methods to [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)) for elements in lists. Unless I am missing something, Q does not appear to have any such built in method. This surprises me as filter is a staple higher order function in so many functional languages.

Let's say I want to filter out all 0's in the list 1 0 2 3 0 4. The resulting list after filtering should be 1 2 3 4. I currently accomplish this in Q by doing:

```
raze{eval(?;(not;(=;x;0));x;())}peach 1 0 2 3 0 4
```

This gives me the result I need, but is slightly inconvenient to read when determining all that is happening is a filter.

I could create my own filter function out of this, but I am wondering if there is just something I'm missing. Is there a conventional way to filter in Q that is built into the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you want to use a wildcard for pattern searching then you might want to use `like`.

E.g. to get all the elements ending with `6`

```
q)l2:("a01";"b02";"c03";"f06";"z26") 
q)l2 where l2 like "*6"
("f06";"z26")
```

Explanation:
1) search the string ending with `6`; `like` will return a vector of booleans

```
q)l2 like "*6"          
00011b
```

2) Now get the indexes `where` the vector elements are `true`

```
q)where l2 like "*6"
3j, 4j
```

3) get the elements where we found the matches

```
q)l2 where l2 like "*6"
("f06";"z26")
```

Answer (score 5):

`except` should be the keyword that you're looking for, if you're only considering lists.

From http://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#except:

> Returns all items of list x that are not (items of) list or atom y.

```
q)1 0 2 3 0 4 except 0
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: This is definitely the best solution to my specific example, and I've used it for that case. I selected nyi's answer since it applies most succinctly to general filtering cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are some implementations of filter functions written by Aaron Davies which might be useful for different use cases.

https://github.com/adavies42/qist/blob/c4840d8b072ff23b05f38aef9ab0a8298a16d902/lib/util.q#L147:1

One example:

q)filter[1<]1 2 3
output: 2 3